Significance of Poincare's inequality
I am self-learning the Evans' PDE book. In Chapter 5.8, it states the Poincare's inequality as

Let $U$ be a bounded, connected, open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, with a $C^1$ boundary > $\partial U$. Assume $1 \leq p \leq \infty$.
Then there exists a constant $C$, depending only on $n, p$ and $U$,
such that
\begin{equation}
     \left\|u-(u)_U\right\|_{L^p(U)} \leq C\|D u\|_{L^p(U)} 
 \end{equation}
for each function $u \in W^{1, p}(U)$.

And it says:

The significance of the equation is that only the gradient of $u$ appears on the right-hand side.

I wonder exactly what is significant about this fact? Is there any concrete applications? In Wiki, it says

Such bounds are of great importance in the modern, direct methods of
the calculus of variations.

and I also want to know how it relates to the calculus of variations.

I believe this is used quite a bit to prove convergence and obtain error estimates in Finite Element Methods.

Proving coercivity of elliptic differential operators to prove existence and uniqueness for elliptic PDE is a major application

Thank you guys for the comments. I am looking for those sources right now. If you guys are free to write down a more detailed answer, I would love to accept it.

For a (probability inspired) perspective: in the case $p=2$, the spectral gap inequality corresponds to exponential $L^2$-ergodicity. Consider the heat equation on $U$,
$$\partial_tu=\Delta u,$$
with boundary condition $u_x(t,x)=0$ for $t\geq 0, x \in \partial U$ and initial condition $u_0$ with $\int u_0 = 0$. Then the spectral gap inequality is equivalent to
$$\Vert u(t,\cdot) \Vert_2^2 \leq C(u_0) \exp(-2t/C).$$
This means we converge exponentially fast to the steady state solution $u \equiv 0$ in the $L^2$-norm.
Proving this is a nice little exercise for you :) The proabilistic interpretation of this is that a Brownian motion in $U$ with reflection on the boundary will converge quickly to the stationary distribution which is uniform.
[The factor of $2$ in the exponent might be misplaced, it depends on if you work with $\Delta$ or $\Delta/2$.]
